# Definition of a sober space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

We say that a topological space is **sober** if every nonempty irreducible closed subset is the closure of a one-point set.

Just to clarify, for the definition of sober, does it mean that every nonempty irreducible closed subset is the closure of *some* one-point set; or a subset is nonempty irreducible closed *if and only if* it is the closure of a one-point set?

Is it guaranteed that the closure of a one-point set is irreducible and closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've gotten your definition wrong: a space $X$ is sober iff for every nonempty irreducible closed subset $Z\subset X$ there exists a unique point $z\in X$ such that $\overline{\{z\}}=Z$. (This is a unique existence requirement; your post originally only had an existence requirement.)

In any case, in any topological space, the closure of any one-point set is an irreducible closed subset: if $x\in X$ is a point and $\overline{\{x\}}=Y\cup Z$ for nonempty closed subsets $Y,Z\subset X$, then one of $Y$ and $Z$ must contain $x$, and hence either $Y=\overline{\{x\}}$ or $Z=\overline{\{x\}}$, proving $\overline{\{x\}}$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you! For the uniqueness part, does it imply that the closure of different one-point sets have to be different?

Comment: Yes. In a sober space, if $\overline{\{x\}}=\overline{\{y\}}$, then $x=y$.

Comment: Thank you! @KReiser

Comment: "every nonempty irreducible closed subset is the closure of exactly one point of " is phrased ambiguously. Maybe this means: "... is the closure of *exactly* one one-point set" ?